# How make automatic crop image according to maximum value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do I make an automatic crop according to the maximum value that I set, for example 1080x1080 in AngularJS, so if the image is too big it will automatically be cropped to 1080x1080 and if the image is less than 1080x1080 then it will be cropped according to 1:1, namely with the same length and width?

The code below displays the image in base64

```
app.directive("fileinputpost", [function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        fileinputpost: "=",
        postfile: "=",
        namepost: "=",
        typepost: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        element.bind("change", function(changeEvent) {
          scope.fileinputpost = changeEvent.target.files[0];

          var files = changeEvent.target.files;
          var ext = files[0].name.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
          scope.namepost = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 19) + "." + ext;
          scope.typepost = files[0].type;

          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.postfile = loadEvent.target.result.split(',')[1];
            });
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(scope.fileinputpost);
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: Since the questione is an angular-js one, please, remove "angular" - which is referred to Angular2 - from the tags.

Comment: you can use a canvas to resize/crop your images, first googled article I found:
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/

Comment: Apart from canvas, what else do you have? @ale